# CSS images not displaying with AngularJS on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, gruntjs, yeoman, angular-fullstack

I am using Heroku - Yeoman - AngularJS Full-Stack - Bootstrap - NodeJS Stack.

Deployment on Heroku is built using 'Grunt build' command. When deployed to Heroku I am having problems rendering CSS images on web pages. Any images within the page are displayed but not from the CSS files.

Eg: the code below does not work

### CSS

```
.aboutpage-header
{
    height: 250px;
    background: url('../images/slider-map.jpg') center center no-repeat scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<header class="aboutpage-header">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h2 class="title">About Us</h2>
        <h2 class="intro"><i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i>Company<span class="highlight">IT</span>
          are experts in bespoke software development and tailored consulting</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

locally it works fine when running `Grunt serve` but as soon as it's deployed on Heroku the CSS images are missing.

Comment: This is now sorted when developing for Heroku just use /assets/images/aboutus.jpg instead of ../assets/images/aboutus.jpg

Comment: You should post your comment as Answer.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, the link should be:

```
/assets/images/image.jpg
```

instead of:

```
../assets/images/image.jpg
```